# JaxB convertendo classe abstrata com Retrofit

Tags: java, web-service, retrofit, jaxb

Tenho um projeto Core onde existe a classe User

```
@XmlSeeAlso(value = {UserClient.class, UserProfessional.class})
public abstract class User implements Serializable {
```

Classe UserProfessional

```
@Getter
@XmlRootElement(name="professional")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserProfessional extends User {
```

Classe UserClient

```
@XmlRootElement(name="client")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserClient extends User {
```

Ao tentar fazer um callback utilizando retrofit recebo o seguinte erro

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class servi.sale.core.shared.user.User
> for method UserService.auth
> at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:755)
> at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:741)
> at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:172)
> at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
> at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.auth(Unknown Source)
> at sale.servi.servisale.Playground.main(Playground.java:29)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
> ```
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ResponseBody converter for class servi.sale.core.shared.user.User.
>     Tried:
>      * retrofit2.BuiltInConverters
>      * retrofit2.converter.jaxb.JaxbConverterFactory
>       at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:351)
>       at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:313)
>       at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:739)
>       ... 10 more

Código callback

```
UserAuth auth = new UserAuth("meuemail@email.com", 1,"1234");
Main.getRetrofitFactory().getUserService().auth(auth).enqueue(new                 
Callback<User>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response){
          System.out.print(response.body());
      }

     @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
          System.out.print("deu ruim!!" + t.getMessage());
      }
    });
```

Inicialização retrofit

```
public class RetrofitFactory {

private final Retrofit retrofit;

public RetrofitFactory(){
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("myurl")
            .addConverterFactory(JaxbConverterFactory.create()).build();
}
```